# How can I show my whole array in DetailView

Tags: arrays, swift

I am working on a ToDo List application.  Currently, the ToDo list shows in Table View as a list and the Detail View shows only the first item, a completed switch and the date completed.  I want my Detail View to show all of the items and dates completed, not just the first item.

My app delegate looks like this:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let splitViewController = self.window!.rootViewController as! UISplitViewController
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as! UINavigationController

    let masterViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! MasterViewController
    let detailViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as! DetailViewController

    let firstItem = masterViewController.listManager.getFirstItem()
    detailViewController.toDoItem = firstItem

    return true
}
```

Now, I've tried to change firstItem to toDoItem to show my whole array but I am getting an error:

Cannot assign value of type '[ToDoItem]' to type 'ToDoItem!'

Also, what to I create in Detail View to accommodate an every changing array?

This is my current Detail View:

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateAddedLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var completedSwitch: UISwitch!

var toDoItem: ToDoItem! {
    didSet(newItem) {
        self.refreshUI()
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    refreshUI()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func refreshUI() {

    if(toDoItem == nil) {
        return
    }
    descriptionLabel?.text = toDoItem.itemDescription
    completedSwitch?.setOn(toDoItem.completed, animated: true)
    dateAddedLabel?.text = toDoItem.getDateAdded()
}
```

Comment: The design of `DetailViewController` doesn't match the requirement to show multiple items. You have to add an appropriate view like a table or collection view and declare the data source as `var toDoItems = [ToDoItem]()`

Comment: Thank you! I have it wired up properly now!